# How do you reduce the width of the screen and put spacing between the navigation words in css

Tags: html, css, width

I tried inserting: word-spacing: 30x; to put gaps between words

```
body {
  width:0
}
```

of the css but it does not work.

the attachment is the image of the website, be aware of the scroll on the bottom of the screen.

[image: website image]

Comment: You should post your code as well, it's hard to provide a thorough and clear answer without it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the body a specific width, not body{ width: 0}.

for example:

body{

```
width: 600px;
margin: auto;
```

}

this way the body will be 600px and in the middle of the screen.

with the navigation just give your (li) margin-left: 15px.

hope this will help.